# php - url split up produces an empty 0 index

Tags: php, url, explode

So i'm creating a php application and is currently working on checking the url.

i am running on the build in development server from php, with the public directory as the root

```
php -S localhost:8080 -t public/
```

when i explode the url, i do it like this

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', rtrim($url, '/'));
```

but if for example type in the url:

```
localhost:8080/index/test
```

the content of $segments is the following:

```
echo $segments[0]; // empty,
echo $segments[1]; // index
echo $segments[2]; // test
```

Why is the first index always there, and empty?

```
unset($segments[0]);
```

solves the problem, but i would like to know why it occours.

Comment: Try `var_dump( $segments );`.

Comment: Maybe it starts with a `/`? If that's the case, use trim instead of rtrim

Comment: that fixed it! o:

Comment: I will post as answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your URL starts with `/`, exploding on that character will create an empty item at the beginning (there is nothing before the first separator). In this case, since you're already trimming `/` at the end with `rtrim()`, it will be a simple fix: use `trim()` instead to trim both sides:

```
$segments = explode('/', trim($url, '/'));
```